# Trying to Update Multiple Tables That Use Same Value

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following situation...

I have two tables lets call them Table A and Table B...Each table has three columns with one column being a foreign key to the other...

I was to update one column but can't because it conflicts with the other table and vice versa.  Is their a way to update both at once?

Here's my example...

> ```
> Table A:
> Contract Column|FeeGroup Column|Allowable
>       102      |       1       | 333.00
>
> Table B:
> Contract Column|Procedure Column|Feegroup Column
>       102      |       101      |        1
> ```

So more or less this is a Contract that holds unique groupers but each grouper can have multiple procedures...Trying to find a way to update the FeeGroup column in both tables at the same time to avoid the foreign key contstraint issues...any help?

Comment: So you have two tables with foreign keys that reference each other? How on earth did you end up with such a design decision?

Comment: As geoqmagas says your problem is your table design. You should fix this and then your problem will be gone.